# Is there an 8-bit atomic CAS (cmpxchg) intrinsic for X64 in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++, 64-bit, x86-64, inline-assembly

The following code is possible in 32-bit Visual Studio C++.  Is there a 64-bit equivalent using intrinsics since inline ASM isn't supported in the 64-bit version of Visual Studio C++?

```
FORCEINLINE bool bAtomicCAS8(volatile UINT8 *dest, UINT8 oldval, UINT8 newval)
{
    bool result=false;
    __asm
    {
        mov     al,oldval
        mov     edx,dest
        mov     cl,newval
        lock cmpxchg    byte ptr [edx],cl
        setz    result
    }
    return(result);
}
```

The following instrinsics compile under Visual Studio C++

```
_InterlockedCompareExchange16
_InterlockedCompareExchange
_InterlockedCompareExchange64
_InterlockedCompareExchange128
```

What I am looking for is something along the lines of

```
_InterlockedCompareExchange8
```

But that doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that doesn't exist. You can implement it out-of-line though, if needed.

atomic_msvc_x64.asm

```
_text   SEGMENT

; char _InterlockedCompareExchange8(volatile char*, char NewValue, char Expected) 
;      - RCX, RDX, R8

_InterlockedCompareExchange8  PROC

    mov    eax,r8d
    lock cmpxchg [rcx],dl
    ret

_InterlockedCompareExchange8  ENDP

_text  ENDS

       END
```

Comment: What register is the return variable for a 64-bit asm function ?

Comment: The return value is in AL, AX, EAX, RAX depending on the size. Here it is put there by the cmpxchg instruction.

Comment: At least since Visual Studio 2012, this is no longer required, although not documented. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Verified for Visual Studio 2012 that this intrinsic does exist :

```
char _InterlockedCompareExchange8(volatile char*, char NewValue, char Expected)
```

However, it appears nowhere in the documentation.

Comment: At the time I was using 2010 which doesn't have this intrinsic. I'm using 2012 now though so all is better :-)