# Generating CMPXCHG (without LOCK) in 64-bit builds using Visual C++ (2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly, 64-bit, compare-and-swap

I need CAS functions to use in a context of multiple threads running on the same CPU (assume that all threads are statically glued to selected CPU, via `SetThreadAffinityMask`).

`InterlockedCompareExchange` generates LOCK CMPXCHG. The LOCK part comes with side effects such as a cache miss, a bus lock and a potential for contention with other CPU, all of which are nice, but feel like an extravagant excess given the circuimstances. Since the competing threads run on the same CPU, I assume the LOCK can be dropped, and I further assume it should result in improved performance.

So this is my first question - do I assume correctly?

--

I know how to generate CMPXCHG with inline assembly for 32-bit version. Also, as per [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5810351/1877011) I know how to do for 64-bit version too, *but* as a function call.

What I don't understand, and this is my second question, is how to generate an *inlined* version of it.

--

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm.. if I was trying this, I would use a macro, (OK, ~~shudder~~), or ifdef so I could easily add the lock prefix later, if I suspected problems or found that SetThreadAffinityMask is an udesirable 'optimization'.

Comment: So if you're effectively guaranteeing every thread is run uniquely (so the only reads and writes to shared data are from a single thread), you're just writing a single threading program. So why use `InterlockedCompareExchange`?

Comment: @GManNickG He is using multiple threads on a single logical CPU. Effectively he is battling pre-emptive multitasking here -- he needs it to be a single instruction so that his thread isn't paused in the middle of `if(x == y) x = z`, but he doesn't need `LOCK` because it's still only within a single logical CPU.

Comment: @CoryNelson: Ah, gotcha. So he wants the atomic update without the memory fence. Just have to use the implementation guarantees of the platform; that is, pry open MSVC2012's `<atomic>` and copy `std::atomic<int>::compare_exchange_strong(..., memory_order_relaxed)`.

Comment: @CoryNelson - Don't have MSVC2012, so can't do... though I suspect it's another intrinsic, which is not in the 2010 version.

Comment: Doesn't matter -- it still uses `InterlockedCompareExchange` for `memory_order_relaxed`. I don't think there's an intrinsic to do this.

Comment: @CoryNelson - thanks for the follow-up. As per usual, I simply reworked the code to not need lock-less cmpxchg to begin with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to answer my own question, but to describe a workaround, of sorts.

For CAS on *boolean* variables, it's possible to fall back to [`_bittestandset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z56sc6y4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which is slower than CMPXCHG, but has an intrinsic form in VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

This is really more of a comment, but the space is a little too limited...

I doubt* you'll get the `CMPXCHG` instruction on its own without the use of assembly. If the region is that critical, use the Interlocked intrinsics, disassemble the output, remove the `LOCK` override prefix and link that in (I'd do this for both 32 and 64bit variants, as inlined ASM is [less than optimal in MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hd5ywk0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), as its always treated as unsafe, causing extra protection cruft to be inserted, which may be worse than calling an external version. On the plus side it'll also give you a more uniform code layout).

I'd also recommend you profile both solutions, with an without the `LOCK`, as most newer Intel CPU's implement cache-level locks, that greatly reduce the performance impact of the lock (Chapter 8 of the [Intel Developer Manual](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325462.pdf) provides a healthy bit of insight into the exact effects of bus locking).

*By "doubt" I mean: it doesn't exist as an explicit intrinsic, and using compiler coercion tricks is **very** brittle, not that I know of any for coercing the emission of `XCHG` or `CMPXCHG` (with the exception of `XCHG (E)AX,(E)AX`, used as an alignment NO-OP).